# OpenAI API for nodejs get "Billing hard limit has been reached"

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, openai-api

I want use openai API in my nodejs backend and create an image and show it in my frontend code. I get the API Key but when I want to use it it tells me:

> "Billing hard limit has been reached"

I don't know how to fix the error I've searched in chat-gpt and in Google but I didn't find anything which solves this problem.

Answer (score 0):

- Go to Settings > Billing https://platform.openai.com/account/billing/overview
- Check the credit balance.  If it is $0, add money to the credit balance. (I set autorecharge to off.  So I have to add it manually.)